# Issue with different z-indexes of fixed menu: How to layer child divs of different parents

Tags: html, css, z-index

This example does't look like a menu, but should visualize the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font: normal 16px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(52, 59, 62, .9);
    }
    
    .box {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      width: 100px;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menu .box {
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    
    .main {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    
    .main .box:first-of-type {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    button {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      max-width: 150px;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    
    .green {
      background: green;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .yellow {
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    .yellow_2 {
      background: yellow;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .red {
      background: red;
    }
    
    .green_2 {
      background: green;
      z-index: -100;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="box yellow">1.1</div>
    <div class="box yellow_2">1.2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="box red">2</div>
    <div class="box green">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box red">4</div>
    <div class="box green_2">5</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to have box 1.2 (.yellow_2) display before all boxes, but keep box 1.1 (.yellow) right between box 2,3,4, and 5. Since the parent divs have no z-indexes assigned, what could be at issue here? How can I position child divs within different parents divs with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index property refers to an element’s paint order in this three-dimensional browser illusion. By default, all elements have a z-index of 0, and the browser paints in DOM order. However, z—index actually gives us fine-grained control over when an element is painted. By assigning a higher z-index we can make the element paint in such a way that it is “closer” to the user while assigning a lower (or negative!)z-index lets us paint the element closer to the canvas.

please refer articles below.

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-css-works-creating-layers-with-z-index-6a20afe1550e
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/
https://sevenspark.com/diagnosis/z-index-submenu-hidden-behind-content

Comment: Thanks, the links led to the solution :)

Comment: `all elements have a z-index of 0` --> this is false, all element have z-index set to auto by default which is different from `0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get my head around stacking contexts and what I think what is happening is

- '3' is in its own stacking context with z-index of 100 (Element that is a child of a flex (flexbox) container, with z-index value other than "auto".) see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)
- div.menu is in its own stacking context (because of position:fixed) and this includes the children 1.1 and 1.2 with z-index of 0
- '2', '4', '5' are non-positioned blocks so the appear below the positioned blocks

So, I don't think you can get 1.2 above 3 (without 1.1) because they are in separate stacking contexts. If you change the z-index of .menu to 101, both 1.1 and 1.2 will appear above 3.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you attempt to help! I was able to figure it out based on the articles from Ravisara. I added my initial question to account for the solution. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to keep the parent divs as is, which defaulted them to position:static, and to assign all child divs any position property BUT position:static in order for the z-index values to take effect. Parent z-indexes have priority, but are being overlooked when assigned a static position property. Hope I got that right and it'll help someone.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
body {
  font: normal 16px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.menu{
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(52, 59, 62, .9);
}

.box {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu .box {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.main .box:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}



.yellow {
  position:fixed;
  background: yellow;
  width:10%;
    top:150px;
  left:45%;
}

.yellow_2 {
  position:fixed;
  background: yellow;
  z-index:1000;
  width:10%;
  top:0;
  left:45%;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  z-index:100;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green_2 {
  background: green;
  z-index:-100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="box yellow">1.1</div>
    <div class="box yellow_2">1.2</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="box red">2</div>
    <div class="box green">3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="box red">4</div>
    <div class="box green_2">5</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```